# Error when R package build for Windows

Tags: rcpp

When I run devtools::build_win()
on the package, I get an error saying:

```
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the 
ISO C++ 2011 standard. 
This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with 
the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

So I have tried several things:

1） add `SystemRequirements: C++11` to `DESCRIPTION`

2） add `CXXSTD = -std=c++11` to `src/Makevars`

3） add `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]` to `read_fastq.cpp` (my C++ code file)

But the error remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CXX_STD=CXX11` as described in [Section 1.2.4 of Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code).

You need to be precise:

- do not omit the underscore,
- do not use the form you would on the compiler commandline.

Plugins are not used in packages.

Comment: I have tried to add CXX_STD=CXX11 as described in section 1.2.4. I think it is still not working. I have updated the change in my GitHub https://github.com/winnie0521/qckit/tree/cplusdocumentation

Comment: That is a large dependency chain. I would recommend you start with a minimal package. Maybe create it via `Rcpp.packages.skeleton()`.  Work out how to reliably call C++11 which works for many of us, then apply it to your `qckit`.  You'll get there.